# Can not find custom post type single page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

This is my custom post type code in `function.php` file :

```
function muslim_taha_khedamate()
{

    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'muslim'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'muslim');
    register_post_type('services', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('خدمات', 'muslim'), // Rename these to suit
            'singular_name' => __('خدمت', 'muslim'),
            'add_new' => __('اضافه کردن', 'muslim'),
            'add_new_item' => __('خدمت جدید اضافه کنید.', 'muslim'),
            'edit' => __('ویرایش', 'muslim'),
            'edit_item' => __('ویرایش خدمت', 'muslim'),
            'new_item' => __(' جدید', 'muslim'),
            'view' => __('نمایش خدمت', 'muslim'),
            'view_item' => __('نمایش خدمت', 'muslim'),
            'search_items' => __('جستجوی خدمت', 'muslim'),
            'not_found' => __('خدمتی پیدا نشد.', 'muslim'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('خدمتی در زباله دان پیدا نشد.', 'muslim')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail'
        ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
        'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
        'taxonomies' => array(
            'post_tag',
            'category'
        ) // Add Category and Post Tags support
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'muslim_taha_khedamate'); // Add services Custom Post Type
```

And this is my query :

```
<div class="row">
        <?php 
   $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'services',
        'posts_per_page'=>3,
        'orderby'=>'date',
        'order'=>'ASC'
   );
 $service = new WP_Query($args);
 ?>
        <?php
    while($service->have_posts()): $service->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="service col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="service-item card text-center mb-4">
                    <div class="image card-header text-center m-auto ">
                        <?php  the_post_thumbnail( 'service',array('class'=>'img-fluid')) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body pt-5">
                        <h3> <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </div>
```

And I have a single page `single-services.php` which must display the single page for each post but unfortunately when I click on each of my custom post type it gives me error 404 .
I have three same structure custom post types,two of them are work correctly but this one not.

Can anyone help me please ?
Thanks...

Answer (score -1):

## Try it for custom post type single page

`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" > </a>`

Comment: I think you should create a custom plugin for this issue to get the all data and pass it into some where which you wanted to use on there